# Reorder div for responsive design in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. I have a row with three blocks:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3" id="B">...</div>
    <div class="span4" id="A">...</div>
    <div class="span3" id="C">...</div>
</div>
```

So that the three blocks are ordered as `B`, `A`, `C`.

If the screen width is small, the three blocks will have one row for each, and are also ordered as `B`, `A`, `C`.

But I want them ordered as

```
A
B
C
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="pull-left">
        <div class="span4 pull-right" style="margin-left:0px;">A</div>
        <div class="span3 pull-left" style="margin-left:0px;">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="span3">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You might need to adjust your spacing a bit, but it should provide you the right order that you desired when screen width is narrower.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `pull-*`. I tried that with only two spans and it didn't work. I have an `A | B` and I want that on mobile it displays `B` on top of `A`. Using your code it displays `B` always on the far left and `A` somewhere on the right

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very simple, effective, and does not require skills to do:

make your HTML structure look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1" id="B">...</div>
    <div class="span2" id="A">...</div>
    <div class="span3" id="B">...</div>
    <div class="span4" id="C">...</div>
</div>
```

now, in your `<head>` element include this :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all and (min-width:1024px)" href='bigdevice.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media="all and (max-width:1024px)" href='smalldevice.css'>
```

in your **smalldevice.css**

```
.span1 {display:none;}
```

in your **bigdevice.css**

```
.span3 {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its a simple example. Hope it helps you.

```
  @media screen and (min-width: 320px)  and (max-width: 480px){
    #row{position: relative;color:#fff;}
   #B{background:#000;width:100%;height:50px;float:left;position: absolute;top:50px;}
  #A{background:#666;width:100%;height:50px;clear:both;position: absolute;top:0;}
  #C{background:#aaa;width:100%;height:50px;float:left;position: absolute;top:100px;}
  }
```

For large screens, you don't have to hide any element. just try to positioning it absolutely.

```
@media screen and (min-width:481px) {
    #row{position: relative;}
  #B{background:#000;width:100%;height:50px;}
  #A{background:#666;width:100%;height:50px;}
  #C{background:#aaa;width:100%;height:50px;}
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to approach it is by using this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
.span3 {display:none;}
}
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
.span1 {display:none;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span1" id="B">...</div>
    <div class="span2" id="A">...</div>
    <div class="span3" id="B">...</div>
    <div class="span4" id="C">...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```